# Rails アプリでの、ユーザー種別による処理の切り分け方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails に限定する必要はないのですが、実装方法で悩んでいます

ある中学校の、イベント情報のお知らせや生徒の情報などを扱う Web アプリで、メッセージ機能や掲示板なんかもある、よくある感じのやつです。

- 校長先生
- 先生
- 保護者
- 生徒会長
- 生徒

上記のようなユーザー種別があり、それぞれに対応する処理を切り分けなければいけません。

例えば、生徒のプロフィール画面には、

- 氏名
- 生年月日
- 住所
- 趣味

といった項目があり、これらのうち「住所」はログインしているユーザーが生徒アカウントの場合非表示にする、などです。 こういった、「ユーザー種別ごとに処理を分ける」という場合どのような方法を使うのが良いのでしょうか？

現時点では、

1. ユーザー種別ごとにネームスペースを分け、それぞれコントローラーやビューを用意する
2. ユーザーごとのパーシャルを用意して、ビューの中に `case` 文を書いてレンダーするファイルをわける

のどちらかかなー、と思ってますが自信がありません。お力をおかしくださいませ。

*※ このWebアプリは架空のものです*

Answer (score 3):

ケースバイケースですが、シンプルなRailsアプリであれば `user.teacher?` であれば `user.student?` みたいなメソッドを持たせて、viewの中で if 文とかで切り分けちゃいますね。

```
<% unless user.student? %>
  <input ...>
<% end %>
```

そこそこルールが複雑で一元的に管理しないと将来が不安、ということであれば、CanCanCan（古い記事だとCanCan）とrolifyというgemを使う方法もあります。

- [Devise + CanCan + rolify Tutorial](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Tutorial)
- [Rails4 + Devise + Authority + Rolifyで管理者権限付きの管理画面作成](http://qiita.com/keisukemizuno@github/items/9c079c275118fa7a0f36)

  - CanCanCanの代わりにAuthorityというgemが使われています。

ただ、僕自身はrolifyを使ったことはなくて、DeviseとCanCanCanだけで済ませることが多いです。

このあたりのgemの使い方を調べながら、ご自身のニーズに合った解決策を選択してみてください。

Comment: 将来的に権限がどんどん増えそうな感じがしているのでCanCanCanを使おうと思います。ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 2):

ユーザーの権限による処理の振り分けを行えるgemとして、「CanCanCan」があるので使うと便利です。
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

実装例
http://morizyun.github.io/blog/devise-cancan-rails-authorize/

Comment: CanCanCanで実現できそうです！ありがとうございます。